# How to eliminate duplicates in textjoin from arrayformula

Tags: arrays, duplicates, textjoin

I have a borrowed piece of code that works on Google Sheets except for duplicates.
The flat-file database is an index of technical articles in forty years of a monthly technical journal.
On a separate sheet there is a list of "tags" which represent keywords that might be used in searches.
This formula looks at three text fields in columns F, G, H - article title, article description, and core skills - compares every word to the list of tags, which is a named range called "tags", and uses TEXTJOIN to list all the "hits" - every word in the three columns that also exists on the tag list.

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(tags,$F3369:$H3369)),tags,"")))`

But it lists every instance despite there being duplicates. Here are a few examples of the results:
"cabinet parts, noises, string leveling, string leveling, tools, touchweight, touchweight, verticals"
"regulating, repetition, repetition"
"tuning, tuning, tuning"

I want to eliminate duplicates. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please post the code that you have at hand?

Comment: What I "borrowed" is the arrayformula-if-isnumber, which I do not pretend to understand. There are four variations I'm trying: 
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(tags,$G11:$I11)),tags,"")))


=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(tags,$G11:$I11)),tags,"")))


=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(tags&" ",$G11:$I11&" ")),tags,"")))


=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(tags&" ",$G11:$I11&" ")),tags,"")))